# Android Architecture Components with Data Binnding

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-lifecycle

In Android Architecture Components docs on the Handling Lifecycle page in Best practices paragraph, written:

**Use Data Binding** to maintain a clean interface between your views and the UI controller.

Can someone provide me with link to example on how to use this libraries together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look into [this Google Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvvm-live/), which applies Architecture Components and the Data Binding Library together.